# processing touch events as mouse events in Android apps

Tags: touch, mouseevent, android

I've tried looking for similar posts but looks like they are all for the browser. I'm running JellyBean and don't have a touch device, so some apps (such as SubwaySurfer) don't respond. Is there a way to use mouse events instead? Would truly appreciate any help

Is the app supposed to take care of this? Or can it be done somewhere within Android?

Comment: What device are you using? The system should handle the translation of mouse clicks to touch events for you. Also are you actually trying to build an application, or just use one if it is the latter this question actually belongs on android.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is a custom device. As of now, I'm just using SubwaySufer to test it out.

Comment: try a different app, or even better try something that came stock on the system, like settings. If nothing is able to get the click events then probably your device has some wacky drivers that need to be fixed.

Comment: I've tried Angry-Birds & that works with the mouse. Yes, I'm also inclined towards some event handling at the driver level.